Can I filter existing search query using pre_get_posts for post_mime_type?
I have a search page with a custom filter that I use to only retrieve posts of 'attachment' post_type. Here is a greatly shortened version:
function MySearchFilter($query) {
  if( ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'attachment');     
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','MySearchFilter');

That works fine.
I thought I could use the same technique to limit posts by mime type like so:
    $query->set('post_mime_type', 'application/pdf' );  

Or
    $query->set('post_mime_type', 'image/jpeg');    

And so on...
These do not seem to work. And all the examples I have found seem to refer to creating a -new- query, not modifying the existing query as I hope to do.
It's as if WordPress simply ignores this property.
Is this possible? If so, how?
